# Creating and using assembler library in xcode

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, assembly

At universisty I have assembler programming project to create high-level programming application, which will use some assembler code as an external library.

So my program in Objective-C/Cocoa would load image, read all pixels colors and then pass those colors to assembler program/code/library which will make some operations on them and then return to main obj-c program again.

I am aware that on Windows/Visual Studio it is easily do-able, but since I'm working on Mac only, I want to do it on Mac.

Please give me some instructions.
thanks!

Damian

Comment: What part of it are you having difficulty with? The Xcode piece of the puzzle should be easy - just create a "static library" project and add your .S files to it.

Comment: My problem is how to load .asm file and assembler procedure and use it in normal high level objective-c code in xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual file name extension (inherited from *nix) for Mac OS X is .s, not .asm. Just add it to your Xcode project, and Xcode knows how to build & link it with your library.

[Uli Kusterer's tutorial](http://orangejuiceliberationfront.com/intel-assembler-on-mac-os-x/) is a nice start to writing assembler with Xcode - although the comments are awkwardly wrapped.

(Update) To handle arguments passed from and return values to C or Objective-C code, your assembler function must follow the [Mac OS X ABI](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/LowLevelABI/000-Introduction/introduction.html), which details how C functions use the stack frame and registers.

Comment: Ok, so after creating and adding .s file to my xcode project, I use #include to include .s file ? And then, assuming that in .s file I have a function called 'myHelloWorld:'  how do I call this function with parameters in obj-c ??

Comment: In your .s file, declare your function as a .globl, and write it so that it can deal with arguments passed from C, as documented in Apple's ABI reference - I've added a link to that above. What you'd #include into your C (or ObjC) is a header file with the prototype declaration, not the .s file.