# How can I include inline assembly code in a C source code?

Tags: c, xcode, macos, assembly

This question is for educational purpose only. I want to know the way to include an inline assembly code (I am using Xcode, with i7 Intel processor) in a C source code.

For example:

```
main(){
int a = 2, b = 3, c = 0;

/*
*Sum c = a + b implemented using assembly
*/
{
mov eax, ??? (a)
mov ebx, ??? (b)
bla bla bla...
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Search for and read about *inline assembly in clang* (it's compatible with GCC inline assembly by the way).

Comment: For gcc, checkout --> http://ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html

Comment: Also see: [using assembly code inside Objective c program (Xcode)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25326307/using-assembly-code-inside-objective-c-program-xcode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the clang manuals (clang is the compiler used by xcode).

E.g., see here: http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#inline-asm

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. Better add some information in your answer or make it a comment.

Comment: @Haris: in this case, RTFM really is the best answer.  There's no "simple" way to explain how to use inline asm.  Although there are some good links specifically about inline asm in the x86 tag wiki: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.  Most of the points apply generally, not just to x86 but to GNU inline asm syntax for any architecture.